# Relation between running Thread and the thread object

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

While learning basic thread management, I found difficulty in understanding these lines (in **bold**) from a book.

> Once you’ve started your thread, you need to explicitly decide whether
>   to wait for it to finish (by joining with it—see section 2.1.2) or
>   leave it to run on its own (by detaching it—see section 2.1.3). If you
>   don’t decide before the std::thread object is destroyed, then your
>   program is terminated (the std::thread destructor calls
>   std::terminate()). It’s therefore imperative that you ensure that the
>   thread is correctly joined or detached, even in the presence of
>   exceptions. See section 2.1.3 for a technique to handle this scenario.
>   Note that you only have to make this decision before the std::thread
>   object is destroyed—the thread itself may well have finished long
>   before you join with it or detach it, and **if you detach it, then the
>   thread may continue running long after the std::thread object is
>   destroyed.**

When does a thread run even after the thread object is destroyed? Anyone have sample code or any reference?

Comment: `{ std::thread th(SomeLongRunningFunction); th.detach(); /* th is destroyed here, but SomeLongRunningFunction continues to run on the worker thread */ }`

Comment: After detach, the thread has nothing to do with the std::thread object.

Comment: The rule is simple: A thread always runs until the it returns from its entry function, or the executable it belongs to terminates.

Comment: The thread _object_ is the program's handle on the running thread.  If the program has no need to `join()` the thread or, to do anything to the thread after starting it, then there's no need to keep the thread object around.  The program can detach the thread and destroy the object in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this means is that the lifetime of the thread is not associated with the lifetime of the thread object.

So the following code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    { //scope the thread object
        std::thread thr = std::thread([]() {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            std::cout << "Thread stuff\r\n";
        });
        thr.detach();
    } //thr is destroyed here
    std::cout << "thr destroyed, start sleep\r\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    std::cout << "sleep over\r\n";
}
```

Will output:

```
thr destroyed, start sleep
Thread stuff
sleep over
```

Comment: This is a *possible* output. "Thread stuff" may appear first.

Comment: @Hi when can that happen?

Comment: The standard makes no guarantee of when the thread will be started. It only says that upon creation that it will be scheduled to start. It's up to the OS to actually run the thread. The only guarantee is that a join will wait until the thread finishes, but since it is detached, we can't use join.